# Is there a way to get the "tel" tag in html forms to work on other browsers besides safari 8+?

Tags: html, forms, input, tel

I am a new HTML student that is learning HTML 4.01 Transitional, and I am STUCK!

I am making a form for a user to request investment information and I don't know how to "cross tag" all the browsers for this tag. Is there a workaround for other browsers?

I got my code from w3 schools, and as stated it only works for Safari 8 but I was wondering if there are other codes that I could use? or if there is a way to relabel the input type="" to something that works with all other browsers; IE, Chrome, FF, etc...

When I run the code it has the "placeholder" box but I can't click on it with any of the other browsers it is quite simply there for looks and nothing functional about it.

```
     Telephone:<br/>
     <input type="tel" placeholder="Enter your 10-digit telephone number:" name="usertel"><br/>
```

Comment: Just a question, 

<input type="number" name="quantity" min="10" max="10">

Comment: would this be a legitimate workaround for trying to get a person's # in the form?

Comment: <input name="usertel" title="Enter your 10-digit telephone number" type="text" />